# Change AD password when outside of LAN will prevent user windows log in?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange, active-directory

If a user with his laptop is outside of LAN and he cannot access his Exchang account, Then I change his AD password which is also the Exchange password, will the user still be able to log in to the computer?

My gut feeling is that the password will only sync when he is back in LAN, but I don't know if there are other tricky mechanism in Exchange that will prevent any kind of access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my experience, if the domain controller is not accessible from outside the LAN, then yes, the windows password will be updated only when the user connect back to LAN (directly or via VPN or something). Until then, cached old password works just fine. Exchange does not interfere in any way with windows logon process.